# python row dividing with one element

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am reading 'Computational Physics -Mark Newman' book.
The following is one of its example.

```
from numpy import *

A = array([
    [2, 1, 4, 1],
    [3, 4, -1, -1],
    [1, -4, 1, 5],
    [2, -2, 1, 3]
])

v = array([-4, 3, 9, 7], float)
N = len(v)

for m in range(N):
    div = A[m,m]
    A[m,:] /= div   <-----------(not working)
    v[m] /= div
...
```

It is one part of back-substitution implementation.
But while dividing div(diagonal element of row in matrix), it shows error.

"A[m,:] /= div

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide"

What made this error? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [2, 1, 4, 1],
    [3, 4, -1, -1],
    [1, -4, 1, 5],
    [2, -2, 1, 3]
], dtype=np.float)

v = np.array([-4, 3, 9, 7], float)
N = len(v)

for m in range(N):
    div = A[m, m]
    A[m, :] /= div
    v[m] /= div
```

Or if you really want integer division:

```
for m in range(N):
    div = A[m, m]
    A[m, :] = A[m, :] / div
    v[m] /= div
```

The issue is that in Python 3, `/` does the true division, so it convert the results to float, and when you do `A[m, :] /= div` you are trying to assign a float result to `A` which is of type integer. You can find more information on this, [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10565#issuecomment-364598965)

As a side-note is generally better not to use:

```
from numpy import *
```